# Common expression for having a rich man's taste but a poor man's budget?

Tags: expressions

What is the common expression for having a rich person's taste and poor person's budget?

Comment: This question might have similar answers as this question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/279808/english-equivalent-to-the-bengali-idiom-bamon-hoye-chand-dhorar-shokh-which-m/279825#279825

Comment: May also be related to: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/303080/is-there-a-similar-english-phrase-for-this-tamil-proverb-lavish-outside-home

Answer (score 42):

This is often described as having "X" tastes on a "Y" budget, where people fill in their own humorous contrasts between something lavish and something frugal.

Two of the most common are "**champagne** tastes on a **beer** budget," and "**caviar** tastes on a **tuna fish** budget" (this last one was parodied on the show *The Real Husbands of Hollywood*, where star Kevin Hart was described as having "caviar tastes" but believing that caviar was spelled with a "K").

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if those were two of the most common due to Robin Leach's ending line on Lifestyles of the Rich & Famous: "champagne wishes and caviar dreams"

Answer (score 18):

> **[Live beyond one's means](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/live%20beyond%20one's%20means)** : to spend more money than one can afford to spend (MW)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please remember that definitions should include sources, and those sources should be cited. I have provided an alternative dictionary definition for you, but encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: I believe this satisfies the concept of spending more than what one "should", but it does not convey the implication that the spending was due to high taste. One could be spending their whole paycheck on Magic: the Gathering cards and certainly be living beyond their means, but their habit would likely not be considered to be one of rich taste.

Comment: This answer is right if you also give in to the tastes although you can't afford to. The question did not specify that you actually spend according to the tastes.

Comment: No. You can live beyond your means while overindulging a cheap sense of taste, or you can have expensive taste and live within your means by not indulging it.

Comment: @BrianR, that seems like a rich taste to me. Maybe it just depends on your tastes ;)

Answer (score 6):

What about "gold collar worker", in the same vein as white- and blue- collar?

> Gold-collar worker (GCW) is a neologism which has been used to describe either young, low-wage workers who invest in conspicuous luxury...

[Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold-collar_worker)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the metaphor: **"Ferrari lifestyle on a Honda paycheck"**

Comment: i think this could be generalized to X lifestyle on Y paycheck, much like the X taste on Y budget above

Comment: Please explain why one could use this phrase. How does it fit the question? How is having a car indicative of a poor or rich budget?